# Duplicate identifier while using Firebase in Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase

> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:12:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:17:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'Promise_Instance'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:130:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'EmailAuthProvider'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:135:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'EmailAuthProvider_Instance'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:144:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'FacebookAuthProvider'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:148:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'FacebookAuthProvider_Instance'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:153:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'GithubAuthProvider'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:157:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'GithubAuthProvider_Instance'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:162:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'GoogleAuthProvider'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:167:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'GoogleAuthProvider_Instance'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:172:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'TwitterAuthProvider'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:177:8
>   Duplicate identifier 'TwitterAuthProvider_Instance'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:181:7
>   Duplicate identifier 'UserCredential'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/mauricio/Development/labs/FrontEnd-Frameworks/Angular2/angular-firebase/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts:339:7
>   Duplicate identifier 'StringFormat'.

How to remove these errors?

Comment: Note that questions featuring just code or just errors, with no explanatory text whatsoever, tend to be downvoted and/or closed. For this question it would probably be helpful for us to see the code in question, and a description of what you did to cause this issue.

Comment: This much is only required for optimum use... I dont like to complicate anything by adding useless things

Comment: Showing what you tried is not useless - it demonstrates that an effort has been made, and moreover it helps illustrate what sort of solution might be helpful.

Comment: @halfer please tell me if it is working or not?? And there is no other answer is there for this question

Comment: Please do not add [solved] to your titles, we do not do that here. The tick mark on an answer below is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply go to node_modules/firebase/ and check app.d.ts and firebase.d.ts exist. if exists then just delete firebase.d.ts. Because both contains the same definitions and that is causing this error. Now stop the webpack using ctrl+c and then re-compile again. This works always